# Informix: How to truncate a table when importing a dbexport

Tags: informix, dbimport

Is there any good way to truncate the data of a table when importing a dbexport. I realize that I need to amend the number of rows in the .sql file, but how do I need to amend the unload file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to load zero rows for the table, then copy `/dev/null` over the original data file.  I haven't checked whether **dbimport** actually goes out to look for the data file when the SQL file says "0 rows to load", but it might well do so, load what it finds, and report the discrepancy.  If the SQL file says "0 rows" and the data file contains 0 rows, then it shouldn't complain.